Why Smith normal form gives isomorphic modules?
I have an answer to the problem but I use some (trivial) diagram chasing by $5$-Lemma. Consider a principle ideal domain $A$ and a finitely generated module $M$ over $A$. Since $A$ is Noetherian, we can choose a finite presentation by the following exact sequence $$A^m\xrightarrow{a} A^n\to M\to 0.$$Smith normal form basically says there are invertible linear maps $A^m\xrightarrow{f} A^m$ and $A^n\xrightarrow{g} A^n$ such that $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A^m @>{a}>> A^n@>{}>> M@>{}>>0\\
@VV{f}V @VV{g}V @VVV\\
A^m @>{b}>> A^n@>{}>> A^n/\operatorname{Im}(b)@>{}>>0
\end{CD}
is commutative with exact rows, where $b$ maps $e_i$ to some $c_ie_i$, $c_i\in A$, and $M\to A^n/\operatorname{Im}(b)$ is the arrow constructed by the universal property of free modules. The quotient $A^n/\operatorname{Im}(b)$ is then easy to compute as a direct sum decomposition of cyclic modules over $A$.
Then one concludes by a corollary of $5$-Lemma that $M\to A^n/\operatorname{Im}(b)$ is actually an isomorphism. Am I being overly complicated on this?

You actually don't need that $f$ is invertible for this, only that $g$ carries the image of $a$ to exactly the image of $b$, for which it suffices that $f$ be surjective. Then
$$M \cong A^n/\operatorname{Im}(a) \cong g(A^n)/g\operatorname{Im}(a) = A^n/\operatorname{Im}(b),$$
where the second isomorphism is induced by $g$. While this is a special case of the five lemma, it is particularly simple because four of the ten terms are $0$.
